# (error: (-215:Assertion failed) total(os[i]) > 0 in function 'getLayerShapesRecursively') when upsampling image

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to improve the resolution of my .PNG file using EDSR method.
However, while running my code :

'''

```
import cv2
import os 

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images


img = load_images_from_folder('imgSource')

sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
path = "imgModel/EDSR_x4.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("edsr",4)

result = []

for i in range(0, len(img)):
    imgRes = sr.upsample(img[i])
    result.append(imgRes)
```

'''

On the line :

```
imgRes = sr.upsample(img[i])
```

It shown error like this :

*error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-tjxnaiom/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:3534: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total(os[i]) > 0 in function 'getLayerShapesRecursively'*

Is there any parts that I have to change? Thank you :)

Comment: What's the OpenCV version?

Comment: OpenCV version was 
opencv 4.5.3

Comment: Could you also show the exact errror? E.g. is there any traceback?